# Posible bug en snippet de SO

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Dentro del snippet existe un elemento `div` identificado como `as-console-wrapper`. Al utilizar el selector `div:last-of-type`, a parte de seleccionar el elemento contenido dentro del código HTML, selecciona también `as-console-wrapper`.

Propongo que **alteren la localización de salida de datos** de la consola, fuera de `iframe`, o que **impidan que se pueda alterar el estilo** de `as-console-wrapper` desde el propio snippet.

```css
div:last-of-type
{
  display: initial;
}

div:last-of-type::after
{
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
<div>baz</div>
```

Ni siquiera se aplica el estilo del selector con el pseudoelemento.

El posible bug también puede ser **identificado sin pseudoclases**. Declarar la regla `!important` es suficiente para ver los cambios producidos.

Comment: Esta es una cosa que ha causado errores en otras preguntas. Pero me parece que se escapa del alcance de Stack Overflow en Español y afecta a todos los sitios de la red de Stack Exchange. Deberías comprobar si se ha sugerido en [meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) y crear una pregunta ahí si no existe.

Comment: La solución sería que hagas un `div` propio para todo lo que se aplique a lo tuyo y los selectores apliquen todo hacia ese `div`, o mejor un `div` con un `class` y todo se aplique a ese `class`.